# stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL context creation failure

Tags: php, phpmailer, swiftmailer

For some reason, since last tuesday without making any change to our server software ( Debian 8 ), I've been having this problem:

> [Mon Jan 13 11:13:07.112949 2020] [php7:warn] [pid 2400] [client 83.240.191.162:42899] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL context creation failure in

We have multiple websites on this server ( around 50 ), and some of them are able to send emails others don't. I've checked the help page of PHP Mailer ( https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting ), and for example the return of this command `echo QUIT | openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587` is ( heavily cropped ):

> ```
> Start Time: 1578912430
> Timeout   : 300 (sec)
> Verify return code: 0 (ok)
> ```
>
> --- 250 SMTPUTF8 DONE

But with PHP no email is sent.

Open SSL is configured in PHP:
[image: PHP OpenSSL]

And also installed in the server:
`OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017`

I checked the time of the server and synced it, we updated the openssl lib also, just in case.

There is at least a site that is working correctly and sending emails through SwiftMailer, but even when I configure other sites with the same config, no email is sent, and always gives the same error.

Also I've updated the certificate library by downloading the cacert.pem file, and adding it to PHP manually.

[image: Cacert.pem installed]

Any idea?

Comment: Update your certificate library. https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: Already done, that, and still nothing, in this specific case, it's not due to that, I forgot to mention that on the question. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to restart your webserver - if that is cached.

Comment: I restarted the webserver, well reloaded Apache, but that is usually enough, we thought about restarting the server itself, but nobody knows how that will work..

Comment: Is there anything weird in `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf`? It looks like your openssl installation is OK, but there's something up with how PHP's using it, which means you need to use PHP to diagnose it. That function doesn't give much feedback, so perhaps try eliminating some possibilities - try disabling certificate verification (see the `SMTPOptions` property); if that succeeds, you know it's a verification problem.

Comment: Sorry @Synchro, nothing strange, and the file hasn't been edited since 2018. I've tried to disable the certification verification, that was my first thought but nothing. The only solution we found was to migrate to a new server. And everything started to work again.